# select from 2 table get rows include foreign key is null

Tags: mysql

Sorry for my bad english.

This is the table log

```
Log
id action product_id table
1  Insert 1          product
2  Read   null       product
3  Update 1          product
```

This is the table product

```
Product
id name
1  A
2  B
```

i want to do is get all rows from log but with some condition.
i tried to use:

```
select log.id,log.action,product.name from log,product where log.product_id = product.id;
```

but it return only the rows contain product_id.
i think this is because row 2 of log do not match log.product_id = product.id

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Search for "LEFT JOIN"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comma separated list of tables in the `FROM` clause implies a `CROSS JOIN.` Adding a `WHERE` clause like you did, implies an `INNER JOIN`. What you need is a `LEFT JOIN`.

You should switch from the old-fashioned way of joining. Your query as it currently is:

```
select log.id,log.action,product.name 
from log,product 
where log.product_id = product.id;
```

rewritten to be using joins would look like:

```
select log.id,log.action,product.name 
from log 
inner join product on log.product_id = product.id;
```

This is not though, what you want, since you want all rows from `log` table to be filled with information coming from `product` table. For this you would use an outer join, namely here a left join. Here's how:

```
select log.id,log.action,product.name 
from log 
left join product on log.product_id = product.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I got your question right, but if you want to include the null values as well in the result, you could do a left join:

```
select log.id,log.action,product.name from log LEFT JOIN product ON log.product_id = product.id;
```

See INNER JOIN, OUTTER JOIN, LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN for more details on how to get values that include/do not include NULL.